# C++ invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’?

Tags: c++, types, casting

I have a code for playing audio in raspberry pi. My compiler is GCC.

When I compile the code, I get the error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’.
```

The error is triggered at the call to `ao_play(dev, buffer, done);`.

How I can fix that? I know that the problem is for casting. but how I can casting in the mentioned line? (`ao_play(dev, buffer, done);`)

```
/*
# install libraries :
sudo apt-get install libmpg123-dev
sudo apt-get install libao-dev

gcc -O2 -o mp3_cpp_audio mp3_cpp_audio.cpp -lmpg123 -lao

./mp3_cpp_audio /var/www/html/mp3_cpp_audio.mp3
*/

#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <mpg123.h>

#define BITS 8


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    mpg123_handle *mh;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size;
    size_t done;
    int err;

    int driver;
    ao_device *dev;

    ao_sample_format format;
    int channels, encoding;
    long rate;

    if(argc < 2)
        exit(0);

    /* initializations */
    ao_initialize();
    driver = ao_default_driver_id();
    mpg123_init();
    mh = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    buffer_size = mpg123_outblock(mh);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));

    /* open the file and get the decoding format */
    mpg123_open(mh, argv[1]);
    mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    /* set the output format and open the output device */
    format.bits = mpg123_encsize(encoding) * BITS;
    format.rate = rate;
    format.channels = channels;
    format.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    format.matrix = 0;
    dev = ao_open_live(driver, &format, NULL);

    /* decode and play */
    while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
        ao_play(dev, buffer, done);  // error belong to this line : invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’

    /* clean up */
    free(buffer);
    ao_close(dev);
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
    ao_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `size_t buffer_size;` is uninitialized when used with `buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));` What do your compiler warnings say about that? You have enabled compiler warnings, right? Also, don't cast the return from `malloc`, `buffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof *buffer);` is all you need. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin We are in C++, you have to cast the result of malloc, it doesn't compile otherwise.

Comment: The error message does not correspond to the code either. The arguments to `ao_play` have type `ao_device *`, `unsigned char *`, and `size_t`, so there could not be a message about "invalid conversion **from** `char *` on that line

Comment: The buffer element type does not matter, interpretation of the buffer content is entirely up to the api.  Older apis use char*, sensible back when it was still common for char to be unsigned by default.  Note that your compiler can still do this, -funsigned-char compile option.  But just cast the error message away with (char*).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - correct you are, my bad, I mixed languages again...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the prototype as given on [Xiph](https://xiph.org/ao/doc/ao_play.html):

```
int ao_play(ao_device *device, char *output_samples, uint_32 num_bytes);
```

This indicates that `buffer` should be a `char*`, not an `unsigned char*`.

Now the issue is that [mpg123](https://www.mpg123.de/api/group__mpg123__input.shtml) indicates that the call to `mpg123_read` requires `unsigned char*`:

```
int     mpg123_read (mpg123_handle *mh, unsigned char *outmemory, size_t outmemsize, size_t *done)
```

According to [basic.lval](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.8), it is safe/not undefined behavior to convert from `char*` to `unsigned char*`, so pass `reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer)` to `ao_play` instead of plain `buffer`.